# How to run Mac OS under Ubuntu reliably?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, mac

I'm thinking of retiring my iMac hardware but continuing to run my DAW software (Logic ProX) under a VM in a guest OS under Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.  Linux has never let me down from a performance and stability point of view.

Is virtual box stable enought to do this (running device drivers for my audio hardware)?

Does VMWare do this?  I only see Fusion, but running under MAC...

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Mac OS X can run under VMware Workstation with the proper license and "open source" unlockers to unlock Mac OS X compatibility.  HOWEVER, running Mac OS under VMware is a license breach in Mac OS software, which prohibits (but doesn't stop you from) installing Mac OS X on VMware.  Getting a Mac OS X installer however, that's up to you, you need to have a Mac to get that installer ISO/disk and then boot to it from within the VMware.

Comment: From what I have read, Mac OS is very hardware specific.  Works well on Apple hardware, but usually needs work arounds for close non Apple hardware to make it work half decent.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!